# Problemas, tratando de instalar libpq-dev en ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-12

Necesito instalar la libreria libpq-dev con el siguiente comando:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Me genera este mensaje:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 libpq-dev : Depende: libpq5 (= 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) pero 13.3-1.pgdg20.04+1 va a ser instalado
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Acto seguido trato de instalar la libreria directamente con este comando:

```
$  sudo apt-get install libpq5=12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
```

Y me genera este mensaje:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se encontró la versión «12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2» para «libpq5»
```

La versión del SO de Ubuntu que tengo es la siguiente:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo, yo estoy en las mismas pero con el ubunto 22.04
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
postgresql-contrib ya está en su versión más reciente (14+238).
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación: Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplida

Comment: Prueba instalando `sudo apt-get install libpq5`

Answer (score 1):

Me paso el mismo problema en kubuntu 22.10, resolvi desinstalando libpq5 e instalando libpq-dev.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libpq5
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```